# How to bind the data from code inside XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have this class:

```
public partial class Calendar : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand EventSelectedCommand => new Command(async (item) => await ExecuteEventSelectedCommand(item));
    public ICommand DayTappedCommand => new Command<DateTime>(async (date) => await DayTapped(date));
    public EventCollection Events { get; set; }

    private void SetCalendar()
    {
        Events = new EventCollection
        {
            [DateTime.Now] = new List<EventModel>
            {
                new EventModel { Name = "Herrenabend, 10:00 - 12:00 – 5000 Scanns", ID = 100},
        };
}
```

and I wanna do bind the data to my calendar.
I tried this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <controls:Calendar
        x:Name="calender"
        DayTappedCommand="{Binding DayTappedCommand}"
        Events="{Binding Q2go.MainMenu_Partners.Calendar.Events}">
        <controls:Calendar.EventTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>

                    <Label
                         Text="{Binding Name}"
                         FontAttributes="Bold"
                         FontSize="Medium" >
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                Tapped="ClickOnLabel"
                                />
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                    
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="1"
                         Text="{Binding ID}"
                         FontSize="8" >
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                Tapped="ClickOnLabel"
                                />
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                    
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Command="{Binding BindingContext.EventSelectedCommand, Source={x:Reference test}}" 
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Calendar.EventTemplate>
    </controls:Calendar>

</Grid>
```

But the data isn't given into the calendar and non of the events fire.
Where is the missing link here?

I thought by: `Events="{Binding Q2go.MainMenu_Partners.Calendar.Events}">`
I am doing everything correctly. but nothing is displayed. Why is that?

I know that if I just give the data to the calendar inside code (calender.events = events) it works just fine (still no event handlers) but i want it to bind the data from code. So without this line (calender.events = events).

I read in every sample that this should work, but it doesn't for me. So where is the issue?

Comment: if your page's `BindingContext` is set to `this` then you should just use `Events="{Binding Events}"` as the Binding expression

Comment: @user13397492 Hi, have solved this? If so, remember to share the solution in answer when you have time.

Comment: Yes, with the help of @Jason. I was just missing this one line of code. He should answer so I can accept :)

Comment: @Jason please put it as an answer so that the op closes the question.

Answer (score 0):

if your page's `BindingContext` is set to `this` then you should just use `Events="{Binding Events}"` as the Binding expression